# How to send test email specifying SMTP server

Tags: email, smtp, redhat

I'd like to test to see if I can send email unauthenticated from an smtp server from my red hat box.

If I want to send a test email from command-line, I would do something like this:

```
mail -s Test addr@domain.com < /dev/null
```

How do I specify an SMTP server to send the mail through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you can't tell the built in 'mail' application which SMTP server to use - it simply uses sendmail on the local system.

You might want to grab the 'nail' rpm and use that instead, as then you can put 'set smtp=serveraddress' into /etc/mail.rc

You could try putting that in now, but it doesn't work on my CentOS 5.3 system.